# Client server application - closing server OR client makes the opposite end display NULL

Tags: java, networking

We've created a client server chat application which enables the client and server to send messages to one another. We are using eclipse and gui as the interface. The server has to run first inorder for the client to send messages and when the client sends a message the gui appears to the server and thats how the messaging starts. The problem is when someone closes the application (presses X in the gui) the opposite ends text field keeps displaying null.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. 
The code is down below :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class AppClient extends Frame implements ActionListener,Runnable
{
 //Declarations
 Button b;
 TextField tf;
 TextArea ta;
 Socket s;
 PrintWriter pw;
 BufferedReader br;
 Thread th;

 public AppClient()
 {
  Frame f=new Frame("Client Side Chatting");//Frame for Client
  f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//set layout
  f.setBackground(Color.orange);//set background color of the Frame
  b=new Button("Send");//Send Button
  b.addActionListener(this);//Add action listener to send button.
  f.addWindowListener(new W1());//add Window Listener to the Frame
  tf=new TextField(15);
  ta=new TextArea(12,20);
  ta.setBackground(Color.cyan);
  f.add(tf);//Add TextField to the frame
  f.add(b);//Add send Button to the frame
  f.add(ta);//Add TextArea to the frame
  try{
   s=new Socket("10.1.202.82",5555);//Socket for client
   //below line reads input from InputStreamReader
   br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
   //below line writes output to OutPutStream
   pw=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
  }catch(Exception e)  
  {
  }
  th=new Thread(this);//start a new thread
  th.setDaemon(true);//set the thread as demon
  th.start();
  setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20));
  f.setSize(200,200);//set the size
  f.setVisible(true);
  f.setLocation(100,300);//set the location
  f.validate();
 }
 //method required to close the Frame on clicking "X" icon.
 private class W1 extends WindowAdapter
 {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
  {
   System.exit(0);
  }
 }
 //This method will called after clicking on Send button.
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 {
  pw.println(tf.getText());//write the value of textfield into PrintWriter
  tf.setText("");//clean the textfield
 }
 //Thread running as a process in background
 public void run()
 {
  while(true)
  {
   try{
    ta.append(br.readLine()+"\n");//Append to TextArea
   }catch(Exception e) {}
  }
 }
 //Main method
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  //Instantiate AppClient class
  AppClient client = new AppClient();
 }
}
```

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: Can you post some code that shows how you are reading messages from the client/server?

Comment: Can you post server code too?